# Reading text file containing mixed data in C++

Tags: c++, file

suppose I have a text file that have text data like:
[image]

I am reading this file in c++ like,

```
ifstream file("book_inventory.txt");
    string content;
        int i=0;
    while(file >> content) {
cout << content << ' ';
}
```

but it display all output on a single line without showing any new line .

Comment: Did you forget `<< "\n";`?

Comment: tried but same result

Answer (score 2):

Read the whole line using e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) then use a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse out first the three numbers. Then it gets a little harder. If the name (like e.g. "James Pilgrim") is always two "words" then you can use normal input operator `>>` to get the names, and then `std::getline` again to get the last part.

If the name can be one, two or more words, then it's actually impossible to say when the person names ends and the title begins.

On the other hand, if you don't want to actually parse the contents, and just print the lines then just read line by line using `std::getline`, and remember to print a newline.

Answer (score 1):

> You can try the below code to read a file line by line as it is or using endl instead of ' ' in your code

```
ifstream myfile("book_inventory.txt");
string line;
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: @NaveedKhan, probably you are not changing code properly, or rebuilding it well. Instead of posting that it doesn't work, can you please try it out yourself? There is definitely something you're missing.